# Web development process - step by step (asp.net and sql server)

Tags: asp.net

it is my first opportunity to develop web application, and I really don’t have any clue where to begin with, I am wondering what should I include in documentation, which method am going to use, database designing, analysis ,though I am aware of this all things as I have done all this as a part of my studies  but, Its totally a different environment in real world, am working on e-commerce application, If any one could guide me then it would be a great help for me.

Comment: You are working on e-commerce application ? a all ready existin one ? a new one ?

Comment: Hi Aristos, yes i am working on e-commerce application, it is existing and i need to redesign whole website

Answer (score 0):

The only real advice I can think of, is to start with the big picture then break it down to smaller problems.

Do this again with each smaller problem (db design, analysis, documentation etc), until you get to something you understand and can work out.

Answer (score 0):

Look up n-tier/ n-layer design.

and if its your first one, maybe stick to a simple pattern like the "Transaction Script Pattern"